# AngularJS directive inheritance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance, architecture

I'm pretty new to Angular and I got a question regarding directives and inheritance.
Let's assume there are two directives:

```
<my-pic    my-log="log pic"       my-warn="pic warn"    my-src="/some/url/pic.jpg"></my-pic>
<my-button my-log="log button"    my-warn="button warn" my-text="button text"></my-button>
```

**JS-Code**

```
angular.module("app", [])
.directive("myPic",function(){
    return {
         restrict: "E"
        ,scope: {
             log: "@myLog"
            ,src: "@mySrc"
            ,warn:"@myWarn"
        }
        ,template: '<img src="{{src}}" title="{{log}} | {{warn}}"></img>'
        ,controller: function($scope, $log){
            $log.log($scope.log);
            $log.warn($scope.warn);
        }
    };
})
.directive("myButton",function(){
    return {
         restrict: "E"
        ,scope: {
             log:  "@myLog"
            ,text: "@myText"
            ,warn: "@myWarn"
        }
        ,template: '<button title="{{log}} | {{warn}}">{{text}}</button>'
        ,controller: function($scope, $log){
            $log.log($scope.log);
            $log.warn($scope.warn);
        }
    };
});
```

**Code Pen**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLMdRL

**QUESTION**

The question is, is it possible to create a third directive from which the MyPic and MyButton directives could be derived from and that handles the my-log="..." and my-warn="..." attributes (the $log code and adding the title attribute to the template code)?
The my-log and my-warn attributes must be handled by the same directive and the attribute values should still be accessible by the child directives.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: directive can only inherited his parent controller scope only if they are nested and child directive has made parent directive as `require`

Comment: Is there an other way to accomplish what I want to do? Like with a service that accepts the $scope and $element object as a parameter? Or is it a really bad idea to manipulate the DOM in a service?

Comment: yes it is bad idea to manipulate DOM from service. prefered way would be DOM..you could think about event `$broadcast` or `$emit` in this case

Comment: but where would I put the code of the event handler in?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you don't need to inheritance. Just write a service to handle your common logging operations and inject it into your directives.

Comment: So how would you achieve the DOM manipulation then? According to pankajparkar it is an bad idea to manipulate the DOM in a service.

Comment: Don't think to manipulate DOM, AngularJS handles this anyway. You should manipulate only your values (state). Logging and changing the values are made by service. I couldn't see any DOM manipulation in your directive code by the way. All variables were already binded. You need a function that it does same business logic, so this is a service method. Give your scope variables to service method as parameter if needed.

Comment: With DOM manipulation I meant that the directive should add the title="{{log}} | {{warn}}" attributes to the template.

Comment: you have already 2 directives, what about inheritance? You have set the templates. Directive adds template to your container and binds their variables. There is no problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found a solution I can live with, however maybe there is a better solution to do this. What I did is, I created a third directive 'myLogger' that is then added to the template of the 'myButton' and 'myPic' directives. I also created a function that is defined as a constant and that adds the logging properties to the scope of the directive. The 'myLogger' directive does the console logging and ads the 'title' attribute to the HTML-element.

Any advices/ideas to improve that solution are very welcome. I would also appreciate if someone has a better solution.

**HTML code:**

```
<my-pic    my-log="log pic"       my-warn="pic warn"    my-src="/some/url/pic.jpg"></my-pic>
<my-button my-log="log button"    my-warn="button warn" my-text="button text"></my-button>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
angular.module("app", [])
.constant("addLogScope",function(opts){
    return angular.extend(opts || {},{
       myWarn: "@"
      ,myLog:  "@"
    });
})
.directive("myLogger",function(){
    return {
         restrict: "A"
        ,scope: true
        ,controller: function($scope, $log){
            console.log($scope.myLog);
            console.info($scope.myWarn);
        }
        ,link: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            $element.prop("title",$scope.myLog + " | " + $scope.myWarn);
        }
    };
})
.directive("myPic",function(addLogScope){
    return {
         restrict: "E"
        ,scope: addLogScope({
            mySrc: "@"
        })
        ,transclude: true
        ,template: '<img src="{{mySrc}}" my-logger></img>'
        ,controller: function($scope){
        }
    };
})
.directive("myButton",function(addLogScope){
    return {
         restrict: "E"
        ,scope: addLogScope({
           myText: "@"
        })
        ,template: '<button my-logger>{{myText}}</button>'
        ,controller: function($scope){
        }
    };
});
```

**Code pen:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVYgew